# Reading A file Till Reaching a char Then Writing in it in PHP

Tags: php, file

Hi this is my problem i want to read from a file till i reach a specific character and then write a string in a new line before that specific character with php i know how to read by fopen i also know how to read line by line i dont know the last part(inserting my string in the line before that)
Look at This example please:
MYfile Contains:

```
Hello 
How are You 
blab la 
...
#$?!
other parts of my file...
```

so know i want it to when it reached $?! put my string in the line before that assume that my string is I did it!

## Now MYfile Contains:

```
Hello 
How are You 
blab la 
...
#I did it!
#$?!
other parts of my file...
```

How should i do this?!?
What i've done so far:

```
$handle = @fopen("Test2.txt", "r");
if ($handle) 
{
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) 
{
    if($buffer == "#?") echo $buffer;
}
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to search for the `$?!` when reading the text.

As you are reading line by line, check it in each line.

Personally, I would read the whole file at once (assuming it is not too big) and replace the string with the vlaue required.

```
$needle = '$?!'; // or whatever string you want to search for
$valueToInsert = "I did it!"; // Add \r\n if you need a new line

$filecontents = file_get_contents("Test2.txt"); // Read the whole file into string
$output = str_replace($needle, $valueToInsert . $needle, $filecontents);

echo $output; // show the result
```

Not tested the above code - might require tweaking.

Comment: Thank You but i still have a problem your code does not understands Enters in the file and when you echo the output there is no enter (/n) in it How should i handle that!

Comment: No it works just doesnt echo /n as output thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your marker, can you make use of `fseek` to rewind back a number of bytes (set whence to SEEK_CUR) and then use `fwrite` to insert the data?

Something like:

```
$handle = @fopen("Test2.txt", "r");
if ($handle) 
{
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) 
    {
        if($buffer == "#?") {
            fseek($handle, -2, SEEK_CUR); // move back to before the '#?'
            fwrite($handle, 'I did it!');
            break; // quit the loop
        }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Disclaimer: I've not tried the above so you may need to play about to get it working exactly, but it would seem like a possible solution (though perhaps not the ideal one!)